# linkedin API person-activities returns 201 but not able to find the updates in web UI

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j, spring-social-linkedin, linkedin-gem

**Request:**

```
POST http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/person-activities HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="780e395e-995a-41e9-83d6-6bac16046edc", oauth_consumer_key="******", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1421211087", oauth_nonce="-973828846827772736", oauth_signature="*******"
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_65
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 187
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><activity locale="en_US"><timestamp>1421211086614</timestamp><content-type>linkedin-html</content-type><body>test2</body></activity>
```

**Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-li-request-id: OJY853L13Z
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 04:51:22 GMT
X-Li-Fabric: prod-ltx1
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=TB24:g=27:u=159:i=1421211082:t=1421253804:s=803971352"; Expires=Wed, 14 Jan 2015 16:43:24 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: prod-nsg7
X-LI-UUID: 9lTE+PInuROg1UwMlCsAAA==
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=TB24:g=27:u=159:i=1421211082:t=1421253804:s=803971352"; Expires=Wed, 14 Jan 2015 16:43:24 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
Content-Length: 0
```

But when I go to my home page @ profile->your network update, I am not able to see my posts.
I waited more than 30 mins.

Comment: I have also checked that app status is live.

Comment: /v1/people/~shares is working perfectly in the setup. Only issue is I have to give compulsary URL which i dont want to display

Comment: I am still stuck and no way i am able to solve this..some help please